# Creating trade flow maps in ArcGIS for Desktop (or any free software)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, polyline-creation, flow-map

I am trying to represent trade flows on a world map where the size and direction of arrows indicate the exports/imports of a given country.

This type of map is commonly found in magazines and newspapers. However, I find it extremely difficult to make.

Is there any function in ArcGIS for Desktop or any free software that would help me in making it?