# How to create arrows lines automatically on ArcGIS, for a thematic map of directed flux?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, flow-map

I need to create a map with the Import and Export Flux between countries. I have the needed data in my table. But I wish to know if there is any tool or extension which will allow me to create those lines or arrows automatically (similar to how we do with labels, but those create words, which organize themselves in the `Data Frame`).

For that all I should do is to indicate lineament of origin and destination, representing the seaports.

I need to do something like this, but with arrows:

[image: Sample Flux Map]

Comment: If you have say 100 countries importing from and exporting to each other don't you potentially have a LOT of lines to represent on your map?  I'm +1-ing your question to try and give you enough rep to post a picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Nando, eles querem um esboço do que tu estás querendo. Podes fazer um e postar editando a questão. Só me passar a imagem e eu faço isso pra ti.

Comment: Take a look at the other questions that have the [tag:flow] tag.  A lot of similar questions out there, such as [How to create a trade flow map in Arcgis or any free software](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/how-to-create-a-trade-flow-map-in-arcgis-or-any-free-software)

Comment: esri arrow special download arcgis 10

Answer (score 5):

There is a distributive flow tool available in the [applications prototype lab](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/).
Here is a [blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/2013/08/26/flow-map-version-2/) and some [links](http://apl.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ce78d53439624c71b8b2963f6a92c62a) and [data](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9d48ce9b6837492e982e980402d3ed11).
Even if you are not looking for this.
 I like it so here.
[image: Dist flow]

Credit: [Brad Simantel](http://www.bradsimantel.com/)
With your edit addition to the question I will add this link for [placing line decorations](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=989&t=91640) with code.
If you desire more help on using arrows add to your question and I can provide some detail.

Comment: Fantastic! This is quite elegant.

Comment: This tool is very interesting, but I need to represent direct flows. In the figure above flows are mixed in the way.

Comment: I have not been through the exercise provided but I think they are all single lines that offset parallel when they are coincident in origin or destination. The example shows 1 destination. perhaps with multiple destination you would get the results you are looking for. Also you can use line decorations to create arrows (however not sure how it would work with this solution).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want could be found in this Esri blog post called [Creating radial flow maps with ArcGIS](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/09/06/creating-radial-flow-maps-with-arcgis/)